# Azure Routing Query

Tags: azure

I have message body in below format.

What will be the routing query for this.  I tried using $body.iBeaconUuid='some-text', but it says "The server didn't understand your query. Check your query syntax and try again." I tried in other ways also but it says same

```
[
  {
    "timestamp": "2020-09-23T17:47:16.136Z",
    "type": "Gateway",
    "mac": "123",
    "gatewayFree": 89,
    "gatewayLoad": 0.15
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2020-09-23T17:47:16.136Z",
    "type": "iBeacon",
    "mac": "123",
    "bleName": "",
    "ibeaconUuid": "123",
    "ibeaconMajor": 0,
    "ibeaconMinor": 1,
    "rssi": -67,
    "ibeaconTxPower": -76,
    "battery": 0
  },
  {
    "timestamp": "2020-09-23T17:47:16.205Z",
    "type": "iBeacon",
    "mac": "123",
    "bleName": "",
    "ibeaconUuid": "123",
    "ibeaconMajor": 123,
    "ibeaconMinor": 123,
    "rssi": -63,
    "ibeaconTxPower": -59,
    "battery": 0
  }
]
```

Comment: put some more details, add some more context. and error related information.

Comment: Hello Jay, I tried using $body.iBeaconUuid='some-text', but it says "The server didn't understand your query. Check your query syntax and try again." I tried in other ways also but it says same

Comment: Samrat, ah, okay. thats much better. consider adding this to the main question, so the question appears fuller.